# How do I limit a number, returned by a JS calcualation, to a predetermined Max value?

Tags: javascript, math.js

I have a JS calculation that returns a number. I need a Javascript function that limits that number to a max value. If the number returned by the calculation is greater than Max(a predetermined value) change the number to the Max value. I am clueless where to begin. Need help please.

Comment: No code? Please give us something that you've tried.

Comment: `number = number > max ? max : number`

Comment: you seem to have a good start already, now all you have to do is turn that description you made into JS syntax

Answer (score 3):

You could take [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min).

```
limitedValue = Math.min(calculationResult, maxValue);
```

Comment: @KennySalter, take two assignemnts with the given limits.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Could you break that down for me please?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert an If statement to check the value of the number and then decide if you want to show the value or an defined value.

```js
const output = document.querySelector('[data-output]')
const button = document.querySelector('[data-button]')

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
const number = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)
if (number <= 5) {
output.innerText = number
} else
output.innerText = 'number over 5'
})
```

```html
<output data-output></output><br />
<button data-button>Random Number 1-10</button>
```

Comment: This isnt at all what I needed.